# Setting pointer to arbitrary dimension array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I want to initiate a multidimensional array, I usually just use pointers. For example, for two dimensions I use:

```
double **array
```

and for three I use:

```
double ***array
```

However, I'd like to set a multidimensional array based on a command line argument indicating the dimension. Is there are way to set an array of arbitrary size once you have a variable with the number of dimensions you'd like?

Comment: Have you looked into using a third-party library? To me, it sounds like you're looking for a matrix class; [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a good option.

Comment: You can try use void*

Comment: @anjruu Sorry, I don't want an arbitrary dimension matrix, I want an arbitrary dimension array object. For example, I want array[0][1][2]...[n].

Comment: @LeeNeverGup Are you suggesting to loop and keep pointing void* to another void*?

Comment: Is there a reasonable bound on the number of dimensions? Is this bound greater than, say, five?

Comment: Unless you specifically need arbitrary row-length-allocation size *within* the matrix, there is absolutely no reason whatsoever to do this in a modern C++ program (and even *that* isn't a valid reason with a decent amount of engineering forethought).

Comment: Also, I would _strenuously_ avoid `void*` in C++.

Comment: [Three star programmers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) are "cool".

Comment: `When I want to initiate a multidimensional array, I usually just use pointers.` <-- That is a sign you are doing something wrong ...

Comment: @anjruu Not exactly - it's a combinatorial problem and I'm going to see how far I can reasonably push it.

Comment: I think we're going to need a little more detail on the problem you are trying to solve. I have to say though, both the solutions presented (`void*` and `double **...*`) make me die a little on the inside.

Comment: @ZacHowland how do you suggest when I need a multidimensional array of arbitrary dimensions? Such as a x b x c ... x z?

Comment: @MichaelLeVine The most basic method is a vector of vectors.  The rest of your question (dealing with an arbitrary number of dimensions) is a design issue:  array dimensions *mean* something in the context of an application.  An arbitrary number of dimensions indicates you are trying to change the meaning to an *instance* of the application.  It is possible, but very messy, and as a practical application is an indication that you did not properly think about your design.

Comment: If it is not jagged, write a multi dimensional array class that stores the data in a single vector. It it is jagged, then vector of vector.

Comment: @ZacHowland I don't see why an array of arrays is any better or worse than a vector of vectors.

Comment: @MichaelLeVine First off, we are talking about a *dynamic* array of *dynamic* arrays vs a vector of vectors.  Performance-wise, there is no difference.  The real difference comes in that vector already has memory management well tested ... whereas your dynamic array of dynamic arrays would be untested (and therefore, potentially flawed).  When possible, always prefer code reuse.

Comment: You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846684/c11-dynamic-multidimensional-array-of-any-type-using-vector-initilizer-list/20848053#20848053

Comment: Questions for you that you should probably clarify in your question description: 1) If your dimensionality is selectable at runtime, how do you even expect to write code like `array[0][1][2]...[n].`? or is that describing CLI syntax you want to expose? 2) Are the bounds on the number of entries in each dimension static or dynamic (ie. known at compile-time? or variable at runtime?)? 3) In what ways can the collection be mutated? Can individual dimensions be resized at runtime? Entry insertion / removal?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this whole question is an indication of a design flaw, you can (**sort of**) accomplish this:

```
template<typename T>
class MultiArray
{
public:
    MultiArray(std::size_t dimen, std::size_t dimen_size) : _dimensions(dimen)
    {
        _data = new T[dimen * dimen_size];
    }

    // implment copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, destructor, and move constructors as well

    T* operator[](int i)
    {
        assert(0 <= i && i < _dimensions); // bounds check for your dimension
        return &_data[i];
    }
private:
    T* _data;
    std::size_t _dimensions;
};

int main()
{
    MultiArray<int> a(5, 2);
    a[4][1] = 3;
    std::cout << a[4][1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want it jagged, you would have to do more math and maintenance regarding the bounds for each "dimension".

The problem you run into has making the dimensions mean something for your application.  Typically, a multi-dimensional array represents something (e.g. a 2D vector can represent Cartesian space, a  3D or 4D vector can be used for manipulating data for 3D graphics).  Beyond the 4th dimension, finding a valid meaning for the array becomes murky and maintaining the logic behind it becomes increasingly complex with each new dimension.

Comment: What would you suggest as a smart way to design a structure to solve this problem:
I have n terms in a function, each with m possible forms. I need to calculate all values for any combination of the n terms with all the possible m forms of the terms.

Comment: @MichaelLeVine What you just described is a 2 dimensional array (one dimension for your forms, the other for the elements on each form).  It is basically a permutations calculation.

Comment: No, but I also need to store the function output of arbitrary combinations of the terms with arbitrary forms of the terms. I'm solving a combinatorial problems that requires a recursive algorithm, so I need to be able to look up previous outputs (because looking them up is several times faster than recalculating).

Answer (score 1):

you may be interested in the following code which allow you to use any "dynamic" dimension:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class MultiArray
{
public:
    explicit MultiArray(const std::vector<size_t>& dimensions) :
        dimensions(dimensions),
        values(computeTotalSize(dimensions))
    {
        assert(!dimensions.empty());
        assert(!values.empty());
    }

    const T& get(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes) const
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }
    T& get(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes)
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }

    size_t computeIndex(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes) const
    {
        assert(indexes.size() == dimensions.size());

        size_t index = 0;
        size_t mul = 1;

        for (size_t i = 0; i != dimensions.size(); ++i) {
            assert(indexes[i] < dimensions[i]);
            index += indexes[i] * mul;
            mul *= dimensions[i];
        }
        assert(index < values.size());
        return index;
    }

    std::vector<size_t> computeIndexes(size_t index) const
    {
        assert(index < values.size());

        std::vector<size_t> res(dimensions.size());

        size_t mul = values.size();
        for (size_t i = dimensions.size(); i != 0; --i) {
            mul /= dimensions[i - 1];
            res[i - 1] = index / mul;
            assert(res[i - 1] < dimensions[i - 1]);
            index -= res[i - 1] * mul;
        }
        return res;
    }

private:
    size_t computeTotalSize(const std::vector<size_t>& dimensions) const
    {
        size_t totalSize = 1;

        for (auto i : dimensions) {
            totalSize *= i;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

private:
    std::vector<size_t> dimensions;
    std::vector<T> values;
};

int main()
{
    MultiArray<int> m({3, 2, 4});

    m.get({0, 0, 3}) = 42;
    m.get({2, 1, 3}) = 42;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != 24; ++i) {
        assert(m.computeIndex(m.computeIndexes(i)) == i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```