# Implementing a lookup array for an array of N integers of limited range

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have an `arr[N]`, and need to implement a lookup array for all possible value sets `arr` can take, e.g. 2^N possible values for the simplest case where the array is `bool arr[N]`.

This can be done by defining an N-dimensional boolean lookup array. For instance, for N=4 and `arr` being boolean, it would be `bool lookup[2][2][2][2]`. `lookup` can then store and retrieve any possible values of `arr` by `lookup[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]]`.

This is awkward to write and perhaps performance inefficient as well, because `N` varies, so the actual implementation will have to use a `for` loop for storage and retrieval. This is a problem since lookups are a very common operation, and making them as fast as possible is the whole point of this exercise.

Are there any other ways to implement this idea?  I would be interested in a solution for a boolean `arr`, perhaps using some kind of bit representation, as well as a more general solution where the range of values in `arr` is wider than just 2.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I believe so. I am walking a graph of permutations, and it's imperative that nodes won't be visited twice, otherwise the algorithm won't finish in reasonable time. Also, I am walking the graph in a particular way, and in most cases won't have to walk all permutations, or anything close to that.

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709529/setting-pointer-to-arbitrary-dimension-array/19725907#19725907 but should be adapted for bool since `std::vector<bool>` is specialized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of boolean values, you should indeed use bits: Any `N` that is tractable must fit `N^2` entries into memory, which is in the order of 2^32 through 2^38 on modern machines, so you cannot reach `N = 64` anyway.

That said, you can use the least significant bits for each array entry, and simply allocate a store of `2^N` value. The bit representations of your array can then simply serve as indices into this store.

Something like this:

```
uint64_t compressArray(long length, bool* array) {
    uint64_t result = 0;
    for(long i = length; i--; ) result = (result << 1) | (array[i] ? 1 : 0);
    return result;
}

...

int* store = malloc(sizeof(*store) * (1 << N));
bool* array = ...;
// Now you can access the ints in store like this:
store[compressArray(N, array)] = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a pretty elegant solution for the case where the range of possible values is of width 2 (i.e. when `array` is boolean). Would still like to consider a case where it is wider, for example 3 possible values.

Comment: In that case, you only need to replace `(result << 1) | (array[i] ? 1 : 0)` by `result*3 + array[i]` (this assumes that you use the value range 0, 1, 2, of course) and compute the store size as `uint64_t storeSize = 1; for(long i = N; i--; ) storeSize *= 3;` I would not use the `pow()` function to compute the store size, it provides less bits of precision then the integer computation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly...
For boolean type it is enough if you use index of element in one-dimensional array to represent your bits.
For example for arr[4]

```
ar[0] = 0, ar[1] = 0, ar[2] = 0, ar[3] = 0    0000 
ar[0] = 1, ar[1] = 0, ar[2] = 0, ar[3] = 0    0001
ar[0] = 0, ar[1] = 1, ar[2] = 0, ar[3] = 0    0010
ar[0] = 1, ar[1] = 1, ar[2] = 0, ar[3] = 0    0011
```

etc...

For arr containing values from 1 to 3, for instance, you can utilize two bits per one value.

Comment: Yes, for the boolean case it is both efficient and concise to just use the bit representation of indices on a single dimension boolean array. But I am not entirely sure it's still the best solution when there can be more than 2 possible values. For example, for 3 possible values, you will be wasting 1 bit per every value you store (since you'll be using two bits to store only 3 possible values).

Comment: Not exactly lost but I understand your point. It might be possible to utilize some way to compress data but it requires knowledge about data itself. If, for instance, 90% of data is 'false' you might store only true values in some kind of hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

So, from your example `ValueRange = 2` as `bool` can take 2 values;
`Size = N`

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

#include <vector>

template<typename T, int ValueRange, int Size>
class MultiArray
{
    static_assert(ValueRange > 1, "Need at least 2 or more values");
    static_assert(Size > 0, "Size should be strictly positive");
public:
    MultiArray() : values(computeTotalSize())
    {
        assert(!values.empty());
    }

    const T& get(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes) const
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }
    T& get(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes)
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }

    size_t computeIndex(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes) const
    {
        assert(indexes.size() == Size);

        size_t index = 0;
        size_t mul = 1;

        for (size_t i = 0; i != Size; ++i) {
            assert(indexes[i] < ValueRange);
            index += indexes[i] * mul;
            mul *= ValueRange;
        }
        assert(index < values.size());
        return index;
    }

    std::vector<size_t> computeIndexes(size_t index) const
    {
        assert(index < values.size());

        std::vector<size_t> res(Size);

        size_t mul = values.size();
        for (size_t i = Size; i != 0; --i) {
            mul /= ValueRange;
            res[i - 1] = index / mul;
            assert(res[i - 1] < ValueRange);
            index -= res[i - 1] * mul;
        }
        return res;
    }

private:
    size_t computeTotalSize() const
    {
        size_t totalSize = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i != Size; ++i) {
            totalSize *= ValueRange;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> values;
};
```

So use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    MultiArray<int, 2, 4> m;

    m.get({0, 0, 1, 0}) = 42;
    m.get({1, 1, 0, 0}) = 42;

    // Just for test purpose:
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 16; ++i) {
        assert(m.computeIndex(m.computeIndexes(i)) == i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```