# Representing a 4D array as a 1D array python

Tags: python, arrays

I'd like to understand how to correctly represent a 4-dimensional array as a 1-dimensional array and so that I can get the indexing correct (i.e retrieve the array entry in the 1D array given the 4 input coordinates ). Can anyone please point me to the correct indexing for the 4-D array?

I have a minimal example here (where I set the odd numbered index entries of the array as 1). The `dim4_index` is the particular counter of interest.

```
#python script to count a 4-d array and check that we get what we expect
import numpy as np
from numpy import zeros
x_arrsize=3
y_arrsize=x_arrsize+1
z_arrsize=x_arrsize+1
w_arrsize=x_arrsize+1
a=zeros([x_arrsize,y_arrsize,z_arrsize,w_arrsize])
print a
#set every entry not divisible by 2 to 1
for x in range(0, x_arrsize):
    for y in range(0, y_arrsize):
        for z in range(0,z_arrsize):
            for w in range(0,w_arrsize):
                if((x%2>0) or (y%2>0) or (z%2>0) or (w%2>0)):
                    a[x][y][z][w]=1




flat_arr=a.flatten()
print flat_arr

print('\n')
for i in range(0,x_arrsize):
    for j in range(0,y_arrsize):
        for k in range(0,z_arrsize):
            for l in range(0,w_arrsize):
                # use stack overflow formula here
                
                #index each unique hit in the array:
                #arrays are indexed as follows:
                # N dim representation: 
                # (Hit, Stream, Block, Thread)
                #formula from stack overflow:
                #  Array[N,M,K,L] - > 1d rep is Array[N*M*K*L]
                #  flat_index(i,j,k,l) -> 1d rep -> (M*N*K)*i+(M*N)*j+M*k+l

                index_firstpart=(x_arrsize)*(y_arrsize)*(z_arrsize)
                index_secondpart=(x_arrsize)*(y_arrsize)
                index_thirdpart=(y_arrsize)
                # 1D representation 
                dim4_index=index_firstpart*i+index_secondpart*j+index_thirdpart*k+l
                val_orig=a[i][j][k][l]
                if(a[i][j][k][l]>0):
                    print("Original coordinates ({},{},{},{}), New index: {},val_orig: {} val_new: {}".format(i,j,k,l,dim4_index,val_orig,flat_arr[dim4_index]))
```

This logic seems to work ok when the n-dimensional array is a hypercube (so NxNxNxN but when I change it to MxNxNxN) I find that some the flattened array is not correctly called (i.e. a zero entry is retrieved when I expected 1).

So my representation formula might not be quite accurate.

Is there a general formula for representing this conversion from 4D -> 1D? And I would prefer a non-numpy solution if possible (the formula for the conversion is what I'm looking for).

Linked formula I tried to use: [Need of an algorithm for arrays index in a flat representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992156/need-of-an-algorithm-for-arrays-index-in-a-flat-representation)

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need of an algorithm for arrays index in a flat representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992156/need-of-an-algorithm-for-arrays-index-in-a-flat-representation)

Comment: You've just messed up the formula from the linked answer a bit. Each time you have an increase in your `z` dim, that means you've gone up the whole size of `w`, so up by `L`, not by `M`. Look over the linked question a little more / work this out by hand for a small array. You need to multiply by the sizes of all the later dimensions, not the size of the current dimension

Answer (score 0):

Have now tried a new example instead starting from first principles:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import zeros
arrsize=10
x_arrsize=arrsize
y_arrsize=arrsize+1
z_arrsize=arrsize+2
w_arrsize=arrsize+3
a=zeros([x_arrsize,y_arrsize])
for x in range(0,x_arrsize):
    for y in range(0,y_arrsize):
        if((x==y)):
            a[x][y]=1 # define as 1 if X=Y=Z
print("2D EXAMPLE")
print a
flat_arr=a.flatten()
print flat_arr
print("DIRECT REPRESENTATION (2D)")
for itr in range(0,len(flat_arr)):
    if(flat_arr[itr]>0):
        print (itr,flat_arr[itr])
print("TRANSFORMATION (2D)")
for x in range(0,x_arrsize):
    for y in range(0,y_arrsize):
        dim2_index=x+y*x_arrsize
        if(flat_arr[dim2_index]>0):
            print(dim2_index,flat_arr[dim2_index])
        

print("3D EXAMPLE")
            
b = zeros([x_arrsize,y_arrsize,z_arrsize])
for x in range(0,x_arrsize):
    for y in range(0,y_arrsize):
        for z in range(0,z_arrsize):
            if(x==y):
                b[x][y][z]=1

flat_b=b.flatten()
print("Flattened representation (3D)")
valid_itrs=[]
for itr in range(0,len(flat_b)):
    if(flat_b[itr]>0):
        print(itr,flat_b[itr])
        valid_itrs.append(itr)
print("Transformed representation (3D)")
for x in range(0,x_arrsize):
    for y in range(0,y_arrsize):
        for z in range(0,z_arrsize):
            dim3_index=x+y*x_arrsize+z*y_arrsize*x_arrsize
            if(flat_b[dim3_index]):
                isValidItr=(dim3_index in valid_itrs)
                print (dim3_index,flat_b[dim3_index],isValidItr)
            
print("\nNOW DOING 4D example")
c=zeros([x_arrsize,y_arrsize,z_arrsize,w_arrsize])
for x in range(0,x_arrsize):
    for y in range(0,y_arrsize):
        for z in range(0,z_arrsize):
            for w in range(0,w_arrsize):
                if((x==y) and (x==z)):
                    c[x][y][z][w]=1
print("4D flattened representation")
flat_c=c.flatten()
valid_itrs=[]
for itr in range(0,len(flat_c)):
    if(flat_c[itr]>0):
        print(itr,flat_c[itr])
        valid_itrs.append(itr)
print("TRANSFORMED (4D)")
for x in range(0,x_arrsize):
    for y in range(0,y_arrsize):
        for z in range(0,z_arrsize):
            for w in range(0,w_arrsize):
                dim4_index=x+y*x_arrsize+z*y_arrsize*x_arrsize+w*z_arrsize*y_arrsize*x_arrsize
                isValid=(dim4_index in valid_itrs)
                if(isValid):
                    print (dim4_index,flat_c[dim4_index],isValid)
                elif(flat_c[dim4_index]>0):
                    print(dim4_index,flat_c[dim4_index],isValid)
                else:
                    continue
```

which now appears to produce the correct answer (the isValid check always shows True - basically the ordering of x,y,z,w loop might not be best to get the sequential ordering of the 4D index).

So the formula I found is:

```
dim4_index=x+y*x_arrsize+z*y_arrsize*x_arrsize+w*z_arrsize*y_arrsize*x_arrsize
```