# template containing either vector or vector of vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have created a template to play with a vector of objects.

```
template <class T>
class ensemble{
public:
 std::vector<T> list;

// Constructor
 ensemble(int i) {
  int j;
  T   *Tptr;

  list.reserve(i);

  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
   Tptr = new T;
   list.push_back(*Tptr);
  }
 };
};
```

In the main() I can thus create an object that is a vector of objects of class T with `ensemble<T> test(100)`, which will generate the object test that contains 100 objects of class T, stored in a vector.

Now I would like to generalize it a make a template that could create either a vector of objects (as above) or a 2-dimensional array of objects, ie a vector of vectors. Any idea how to do that with the same template ?

Many thanks in advance !
Xtof

Comment: There are `i` memory leaks, one per `new`. C++ ain't Java.

Comment: Following may help you : [Setting pointer to arbitrary dimension array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709529/setting-pointer-to-arbitrary-dimension-array/19725907#19725907)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need neither to call `reserve` nor do the loop in the constructor. It can all be done in one go by calling the right constructor in the `ensemble` initializer list:

```
ensamble(int i)
    : list(i, T())
{}
```

That will cause the vector to be created to contain `i` default-constructed items.

As for creating an instance of `ensemble` using a vector, it's like doing it for any other type:

```
// Creates an instance containing 100 integers
ensemble<int> e1(100);

// Create an instance containing 100 vectors of integer
ensemble<std::vector<int>> e2(100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the constructor. Good to know. Otherwise, the way you create the vector of vectors is not what I'm looking for. Actually, the second dimension is missing. I would rather prefer a template to create a class that contains the vector of vectors. The brute force would be to create one class for the vector, as I did, and another class to contain the vector of vectors. But I would like to have all in one class. Maybe with a template specialization ?