# How to allocate & access 3D, 4D, 5D arrays?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I allocate 3D, 4D, 5D arrays with one malloc in a contigious way and access the individual items?

Something like this:

```
int* array = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);
int item = array[x + y * width];
```

Comment: The same way you just showed. Just keep adding multipliers.

Comment: multipliers? Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered here ([Setting pointer to arbitrary dimension array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19725907/2684539)
):

Look specially `computeIndex`/`computeIndexes`.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MultiArray
{
public:
    explicit MultiArray(const std::vector<size_t>& dimensions) :
        dimensions(dimensions),
        values(computeTotalSize(dimensions))
    {
        assert(!dimensions.empty());
        assert(!values.empty());
    }

    const T& get(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes) const
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }
    T& get(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes)
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }

    size_t computeIndex(const std::vector<size_t>& indexes) const
    {
        assert(indexes.size() == dimensions.size());

        size_t index = 0;
        size_t mul = 1;

        for (size_t i = 0; i != dimensions.size(); ++i) {
            assert(indexes[i] < dimensions[i]);
            index += indexes[i] * mul;
            mul *= dimensions[i];
        }
        assert(index < values.size());
        return index;
    }

    std::vector<size_t> computeIndexes(size_t index) const
    {
        assert(index < values.size());

        std::vector<size_t> res(dimensions.size());

        size_t mul = values.size();
        for (size_t i = dimensions.size(); i != 0; --i) {
            mul /= dimensions[i - 1];
            res[i - 1] = index / mul;
            assert(res[i - 1] < dimensions[i - 1]);
            index -= res[i - 1] * mul;
        }
        return res;
    }

private:
    size_t computeTotalSize(const std::vector<size_t>& dimensions) const
    {
        size_t totalSize = 1;

        for (auto i : dimensions) {
            totalSize *= i;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

private:
    std::vector<size_t> dimensions;
    std::vector<T> values;
};

int main()
{
    MultiArray<int> m({3, 2, 4});

    m.get({0, 0, 3}) = 42;
    m.get({2, 1, 3}) = 42;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != 24; ++i) {
        assert(m.computeIndex(m.computeIndexes(i)) == i);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a131a2959c42f919)

Answer (score 3):

A 3D array is an array of 2D arrays. A 4D array is an array of 3D arrays. You just multiply by your other dimensions. For example, a 3D array can be allocated in this way:

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height * depth);
```

A 4D array can be made by multiplying by your other dimension:

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height * depth * other_dimension);
```

and so on for 5D, 6D, etc. arrays.

You can access elements by using something like this (for 3D arrays, easily extended), assuming you have access to the width and height of the array:

```
int get_element(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return array[(z * width * height) + (y * width) + x];
}
```

For 4D arrays:

```
int get_element(int x, int y, int z, int dimension_4)
{
    return array[(dimension_4 * width * height * depth) + (z * width * height) + (y * width) + x];
}
```

Comment: Yes but how do you access each item? In 3D, 4D, 5D etc.

Comment: Is it possible to do the access without so many multiplications? :)

Comment: Not that I know of. Jared42's answer requires the same number of multiplications, just in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are by nature allocated as a single dimension. You bestow dimensionality on them via the way you compute indexes to them. The size you need to allocate is the size of a scalar element multiplied by the number of elements in each of however many dimensions you intend to use, e.g., if you want a 10 x 20 x 30 array of 4-byte elements, multiply 4 x 10 x 20 x 30 to get the size of the malloc you need. Then, I'd probably write a function such as `my_index(int i, int j, int k)` that would compute the one-dimensional index for any valid (i,j,k) combination. This idea can be extended into as many dimensions as you wish.