# unique_ptr's of zero size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, unique-ptr

I often work with multi-dimensional arrays, and I am not a big fan of `std::vector`, since it is not possible to instantiate a `std::vector` or a `std::vector` of `std::vector`'s using a reference without copying the underlying data.

For one-dimensional arrays, I use the following

```
template<typename T>
using deleted_aligned_array = std::unique_ptr<T[], std::function<void(T*)> >;

template<typename T>
deleted_aligned_array<T> deleted_aligned_array_create(size_t n) {
  return deleted_aligned_array<T>((T*)_mm_malloc(n*sizeof(T),16), [](T* f)->void { _mm_free(f);});
}
```

This is very convenient and allows me to instantiate a dynamically sized array, which also works for a size of zero. Further, I can use `std::forward` to pass on the data without copying.

For a two-dimensional array, I would like to do something like

```
template<typename T>
using deleted_aligned_array2 = std::unique_ptr<T*,std::function<void(T**)>>;

template<typename T>
deleted_aligned_array2<T> deleted_aligned_array_create(size_t m, size_t n) {
  auto arr = deleted_aligned_array2(new T*[m](), [&](T** x) {
                                              if (malloc_usable_size(x) > 0) {
                                                _mm_free(&(x[0][0]));
                                              }
                                              delete[] x;});
  if (m*n > 0) {
    arr.get()[0] = (T*) _mm_malloc(m*n*sizeof(T),16);

    // Row pointers
    for (size_t iRow = 1; iRow < m; iRow++) {
      (m_data.get())[iRow] = &(m_data.get()[0][iRow*n]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

It works for zero-size arrays, but I get an error from `valgrind` for obvious reasons, `invalid read of size 8`.

Is it possible to solve this in an elegant way, without creating an entire class keeping a `std::unique_ptr` member, where I implement move-constructor, move-assignment etc. Ultimately, I would like to generalize this to be used for any dimension

```
template<typename T, size_t Dim>
deleted_aligned_array<T,D> deleted_aligned_array_create(...);
```

The returned array should be a unique pointer with row pointer recursively initialized and it should support zero-size arrays, e.g.

```
auto arr = deleted_aligned_array_create<float,3>(4,5,10);
```

should return a 3-dimensional array with row and column pointers.

Issues:
  1) Avoid reading invalid data in a simple way.
  2) Use a template parameter `D` for generating the types: `T*`, `T**` and simply passing on `D` to code recursively generating row pointers (this I already have).
  3) Preferably in a portable way. `malloc_usable_size` is a GNU extension and calling it on `x` results in an invalid read, when the size is 0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"std::vector or a std::vector of std::vector's using a reference without copying the underlying data"* What do you mean ?

Comment: A good way to implement multidimensional array is to flatten the array and do the index computing "manually".

Comment: If you want to use std::vector as an argument type for say a function you need to create an instance and this issues a copy. I often use sub-arrays of multi-dimensional arrays and want to avoid copying.

Comment: I could use ArrayRef from llvm but it requires llvm.

Comment: No, indexing is risky. A little typo can result in errors and once you work with sub-arrays of a 3-dimensional array it gets complicated

Comment: Indexing is risky? Hide the array so one one can directly access and mis-index it, provide an accessor function that does the indexing, and test the <expletive deleted> out of the accessor. Solved. Typically get a decent performance boost from the cache-friendliness of the 1D array as well.

Comment: The 2D approach is equally cache friendly. Note how all data is contiguously allocated. The accessor function adds the same complexity as establishing row pointers.

Comment: Related [setting-pointer-to-arbitrary-dimension-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709529/setting-pointer-to-arbitrary-dimension-array)

Comment: Its related but as I have written, I already have a recursive function for setting pointers. The issue is the safe deletion and preferable without the need for writing a full class and overloading operators. This I have just done and will post the solution tomorrow. My function for retrieving sub-arrays hints prefetching and beats a murky indexing function. Thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of found a solution but it is not very elegant. If you have a more elegant solution, please post your answer. The solution here is pretty ugly, once we get to higher dimensions.

```
template <class T, size_t D>
class deleted_aligned_multi_array {
};

template <class T>
class deleted_aligned_multi_array<T,1> : public std::unique_ptr<T[], std::function<void(T*)> > {
  deleted_aligned_multi_array(size_t n) :
    std::unique_ptr<T[], std::function<void(T*)> >((T*)_mm_malloc(n*sizeof(T),16),
                                                   [](T* f)->void { _mm_free(f);}) {}
};

template <class T>
class deleted_aligned_multi_array<T,2> {
public:
  typedef T** pointer;
  typedef std::unique_ptr<T*, std::function<void(T**)>> deleted_unique_array;

  deleted_aligned_multi_array() : m(0), n(0), data() {}

  deleted_aligned_multi_array(size_t m, size_t n) : m(m), n(n) {
    if (m*n > 0) {
      data = deleted_unique_array(new T*[m](),
                                    [&](T** x) {
                                      if (sps::msize(x) > 0) {
                                        _mm_free(&(x[0][0]));
                                      }
                                      delete[] x;});

      data.get()[0] = (T*) _mm_malloc(m*n*sizeof(T),16);

      for (size_t iRow = 1; iRow < m; iRow++) {
        (data.get())[iRow] = &(data.get()[0][iRow*n]);
      }
    }
    else {
      data.reset();
    }
  }

  deleted_aligned_multi_array(deleted_aligned_multi_array&& other) : m(other.m), n(other.n),
                                 data(std::move(other.data)) {}

  deleted_aligned_multi_array& operator=( deleted_aligned_multi_array&& other ) {
    if (this != &other) {
      data = std::move( other.data );
      m    = other.m;
      m    = other.n;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  T& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) {
    return this->data.get()[0][i*n + j];
  }

  T* operator[](size_t m) {
    return &(data.get()[m][0]);
  }

  const T* operator[](size_t m) const {
    return data.get()[m];
  }

  pointer get() const {
    return data.get();
  }

  void reset(pointer __p = pointer()) {
    data.reset(__p);
  }

  template<typename _Up>
  void reset(_Up) = delete;

private:
  deleted_aligned_multi_array(const deleted_aligned_multi_array& other) = delete;
  deleted_aligned_multi_array& operator=( const deleted_aligned_multi_array& a ) = delete;

public:
  size_t m;                   ///<Number of rows
  size_t n;                   ///<Number of columns
  deleted_unique_array data;  ///<Data
};
```

A utility function for accessing a sub array, can now easily be made

```
template <class T>
std::unique_ptr<T*, std::function<void(T*)> sub_array(size_t m, size_t n, size_t i, size_t j) {
  // Establish row pointers with reference i and j and dimension mxn.
}
```